# Promise.method() function not working the way I expect it to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, cryptojs

I am writing some code that encrypts a communication channel between two users.
The steps are as follows

- Check if a cipher for the channel exists in `mongoDb`
- If yes, fetch the `cipher` and encrypt the incoming data
- If no, create a new cipher, save it to `mongoDb` and encrypt the incoming data

The code uses `crypto` module which is one of the few synchronous libs in core nodejs

Create a cipher and return it as a promise

```
cipher.createCipher = Promise.method((pw) => {
  if (!pw) {
    throw new Error('Passphrase must be provided');
  }
  return crypto.createCipher('aes192', pw);
});
```

Encrypt data using Promise.method()

```
cipher.encryptTextAsPromise = Promise.method((cipher, plainText) => {
  if (!( typeof plainText === 'string')) {
    throw new Error("2nd param must be plain text");
    let cipherText = '';
    cipher.on('readable', () => {
      var data = cipher.read();
      if (data)
        cipherText += data.toString('hex');
    });
    cipher.on('end', () => {
      return cipherText;
    });
    cipher.write(plainText);
    cipher.end();
  }
});
```

Encrypt data via callback functions.

```
cipher.encryptText = (cipher, plainText, callback) => {
  if (!( typeof plainText === 'string')) {
    throw new Error("2nd param must be plain text");
  }
  try {
    let cipherText = '';
    cipher.on('readable', () => {
      var data = cipher.read();
      if (data)
        cipherText += data.toString('hex');
    });
    cipher.on('end', () => {
      callback(null, cipherText);
    });
    cipher.write(plainText);
    cipher.end();
  } catch (e) {
    callback(e, null);
  }
}
```

I am unable to chain these two together. What I have is a **horrible anti-pattern** that is worse than getting stuck in callback hell

```
cipher.createCipher('secretWord')
  .then((data) => {
    cipher.encryptTextasPromise(data, 'hello world')
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })

mongoDbSearch(username)
  .then((data) => {
    if (data) {
      // Cipher exists, retrieve and encrypt
    }else {
      // Create new cipher and save
      someMongoSave()
        .then((data) => {
          // Cipher exists now, retrieve and encrypt
        })
    }
  })
  .catch((mongoErr) => {
    console.log(mongoErr);
  })
```

The code is a bit incomplete as I am still trying to grasp this concept. Furthermore the my attempt to chain `createCipher` and `encryptTextAsPromise` is returning `undefined` in the data. I have tried writing these as normal callback and then using `Promise.promisfyAll()` as well, which just feels like another anti-pattern.

Comment: well, `cipher.encryptTextAsPromise` never returns a value, so would resolve as `undefined` - even once you fix the logic

Comment: And after throwing an error the subsequent lines are not executed!

Comment: It's not an answer, but I'm fairly sure you're using `Promise.method` incorrectly. From [the documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html), it's clear that it's meant to bridge from a **synchronous** method that may either return its result or throw an error. Your functions aren't synchronous. Moreover, since you're the one writing them, there's no need to wrap them; just use `Promise` within them: http://pastie.org/10971651 (Also note that Pastie fixes the issue @undefined noted above.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - the sample shown [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html) look like the OP is doing it right

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last block of code can be rewritten as [this](https://jsfiddle.net/toxjgrhh/1/)

Comment: @Jaromanda - No, that function *returns* something. The OP's doesn't.

Comment: @Jaromanda: Yeah, once the functons are defined correctly, that's exactly the direction the usage would take.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was addressing the fact that you seemed to be concerned with the fact that the functions were not synchronous - I noted the `logic` error in `cipher.encryptTextAsPromise` and the fact that it doesn't return anything

Comment: @Varun: Are you happy to look at doing it *without* `Promise.method`? It would make those functions a bit simpler.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I am perfectly fine to use whatever method is most suitable. its just, I thought Promise.method is a good way to wrap synchronous code using bluebird.

Comment: @JaromandaX In promise.method() If I use `return someVal`, that gets returned correct? Cause in `cipher.on('end)`, I do return the value of the encrypted text. This same thing works for `createCipher` method, as I am returning a value.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal: Yes, but that `return` returns the value from the `.on('end' ...)` callback (whereupon it's ignored), not the function passed to `Promise.method`.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal - *"I thought Promise.method is a good way to wrap synchronous code using bluebird."* Indeed. But some of your code isn't synchronous, so... :-)

Comment: From my understanding, Promise.method is a way to wrap code that can return synchronous value **or** a Promise - based on the sample in the documentation

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @Jaromanda  aah I understood the mistake. Async code in promise.method() causes lot of potential issues as mentioned in bluebird docs. Completely forgot about that. So I can use Promise.method() for the `createCipher` part, use promise as shown by T.J Crowder for encrypting the text, and for `mongodb` I typically use `Promise.promisifyAll()`. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: @VarunAgarwal - I can't answer the last part of that, but yes, the first part is spot-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.method` would appear to make sense for `createCipher`, but probably not for `encryptTextAsPromise`.

Here's a version that should point you the right direction, distilling various of [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s, [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x)'s, and [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/undefined)'s comments on the question; see code comments for more:

```
// For this one, `Promise.method` still makes sense (although doing it with
// your own promise is also perfectly reasonable)
cipher.createCipher = Promise.method(pw => {
  if (!pw) {
    throw new Error('Passphrase must be provided');
  }
  return crypto.createCipher('aes192', pw);
});

// For this one, your own promise makes sense
cipher.encryptTextAsPromise = (cipher, plainText) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (!( typeof plainText === 'string')) {
      // It's fine to throw here (it will get converted into a rejection),
      // or add `reject` to the arguments list above and call
      // that and return instead:
      // reject(new Error("2nd param must be plain text"));
      // return;
      throw new Error("2nd param must be plain text");
    }
    let cipherText = '';
    cipher.on('readable', () => {
      var data = cipher.read();
      if (data)
        cipherText += data.toString('hex');
    });
    cipher.on('end', () => {
      resolve(cipherText);
    });
    cipher.write(plainText);
    cipher.end();
  });
};

// Usage:
cipher.createCipher('secretWord')
.then(data => cipher.encryptTextAsPromise(data, 'hello world'))
.then(data => console.log(data)) // See 1 below
.catch(err => console.log(err));

mongoDbSearch(username)
.then(data => data || someMongoSave(data)) // You pass `data` to `someMongoSave`, presumably?
.then(data => {
    // Cipher exists, retrieve and encrypt
})
.catch(mongoErr => {
    console.log(mongoErr);
});
```

Separately, re

```
if (!( typeof plainText === 'string')) {
```

there's a `!==` operator in JavaScript. Jus' sayin'. ;-D

Comment: in `encryptTextAsPromise`, is there any reason why you have not added `reject` and removed the `try catch` block. Because of the cipher is not a valid type, the encryption will throw an error as well.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal: No reason at all, in fact I was going to note that. Either is absolutely fine. Throwing in the `Promise` constructor callback is converted into a rejection, so some like to do that because it's more like the synchronous code would be.

Comment: `You pass data to someMongoSave, presumably?` data would be guaranteed to be falsey at that point, so, I don't think so

Comment: in the .then blocks. `data => cipher.encryptTextAsPromise()` is an example of a `map`?

Comment: @VarunAgarwal: It's taking the resolution value (`data`) and then returning the result of calling `cipher.encryptTextAsPromise` passing in that value and `'hello world'`. The promise that `then` callback creates is then resolved/rejected on the basis of the promise `encryptTextAsPromise` returns, and the chain continues.